# constructor and templates

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I was going through this piece of code where I came across a while calling this code from main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class abc
{
public:
enum example
{
a=1,
b=2,
c=3,
d=4
};
};

template<typename T>
class xyz
{
public:
xyz(T &v,abc::example ex=abc::a):b(v),len(sizeof(T))
{
}

protected:
T &b;
int len;
};

#define Buffer_length 1024

template<typename T>
class demo
{
public:
demo(T &v):b(v)
{
length=v.size();
cout<<"length:"<<length<<endl;
typename T::size_type i=0;
for(;i<length;++i)
{
*(Buffer+i)=v[i];
}
}

protected:
typename T::size_type length;
typename T::value_type Buffer[Buffer_length];
T &b;
};
```

Well I am not sure whether this is the correct way of calling the constructor"demo", however when I tried like this:

```
int main()
{
string str="Hello world";
xyz<string> obj1(str,abc::example::a);
demo<xyz> obj2(obj1);
}
```

I got the following error:

```
In function 'int main()':
58:9: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list    for 'template<class T> class demo'
58:9: error:   expected a type, got 'xyz'
58:15: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
58:20: error: cannot convert 'xyz<std::basic_string<char> >' to 'int' in  initialization
58:11: warning: unused variable 'obj2' [-Wunused-variable]
```

I would like to know how to call the constructor demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xyz` is not a concrete type. You cannot use it to instantiate `demo`.

`xyz<string>` is a concrete type, though. It looks like you're trying to use

```
demo<xyz<string> >
```

Comment: I tried it but again,the following errors:In instantiation of 'class demo<xyz<std::basic_string<char> > >':
58:28:   required from here
49:23: error: no type named 'size_type' in 'class xyz<std::basic_string<char> >'
50:44: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'class xyz<std::basic_string<char> >'
 In instantiation of 'demo<T>::demo(T&) [with T = xyz<std::basic_string<char> >]':
58:28:   required from here
39:7: error: 'class xyz<std::basic_string<char> >' has no member named 'size'
39:7: error: using invalid field 'demo<T>::length'
40:16: error: using invalid field 'demo<T>::length'

Comment: It's correct - ``xyz<string>`` doesn't have these members. It's hard for me to guess what was the intent here. Did you mean to instantiate ``demo<string>`` at all?